# Ads Insights API Website Conversions not Available

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I am getting the Facebook Ads Insights data via Marketing API v2.11

API end points: https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/act_XXXXXXX/insights

Where XXXXXXX is an Ad Account Id

But I am not able to fetch the "Website Conversions" data.Also I don't see this field available in the insights fields list https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/fields/v2.11

So how to get this data via api?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The  "Website Conversions" data available on the fields `action_values` and `actions`. It returns [`list<AdsActionStats>`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ads-action-stats/), containing a list of action_type and value.

```
// extracts of action_type

offsite_conversion.add_to_cart: Adds to Cart
offsite_conversion.checkout: Checkouts
offsite_conversion.custom.<custom_conv_id>: Custom Conversions defined by the advertiser
offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_add_payment_info: Adds Payment Info
offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_add_to_cart: Adds To Cart
offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_add_to_wishlist: Adds To Wishlist
offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_complete_registration: Completed Registration
offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_custom: Custom pixel events defined by the advertiser
offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_initiate_checkout: Initiates Checkout
offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_lead: Leads
offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_purchase: Purchases
offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_search: Searchs
offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_view_content: Views Content
offsite_conversion.key_page_view: Key Page Views
offsite_conversion.lead: Leads
offsite_conversion.other: Other Website Conversions
offsite_conversion.registration: Registrations
onsite_conversion.flow_complete: On-Facebook Workflow Completions
onsite_conversion.messaging_block: Blocked Messaging Conversations
onsite_conversion.messaging_first_reply: New Messaging Conversations
onsite_conversion.messaging_reply: Messaging Replies
onsite_conversion.purchase: On-Facebook Purchases
```

Comment: I already have actions and action_values field but the data is not matching with the FB UI.

Comment: what's your request params? can you show how you request the API?

Comment: Anyways I have sorted out the issue.The problem here is there is a big confusion between, whats being shown in UI vs what the API returns.So When we check the Conversions in FB UI the Default attribution window is 28 Day View through and 28 Day Click through, but the API Returns the data with the default attribution window of 1 Day View Through and 28 Day click through.Anyone would get easily confused

Comment: How to get "name of Custom Conversions" via custom_conv_id?