# Getting the main conversion of a campaign

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I need to extract the main conversion and its value for each campaign via Facebook API.

But I can only pull these attributes on the fields `action_values` and `actions`
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47826753

```
offsite_conversion.custom.<custom_conv_id>: Custom Conversions defined by the advertiser
offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_add_payment_info: Adds Payment Info
offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_add_to_cart: Adds To Cart
...
```

In the Facebook UI, what I need is called Results and Results indicator
[image]

Any suggestions please?
Thank you!